# 301 redirect pdf files to my new site

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a folder on my site that contains bunch of pdf files. Is there a way to redirect any one trying to access these files to my new site?

for example if a user tries to access `http://www.example.com/pdf/file.pdf` he gets redirected `http://example2.com`.

I've managed to redirect normal posts using a wordpress 301 redirect plugin, however this is not working with pdf files.

I tried some htaccess rewrite i found on google but it broke the site.

Thanks.

Is there a way to redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule at top of your .htaccess (just below `RewriteEngine` line):

```
RewriteRule ^.+\.pdf$ http://example2.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
```